# how to implement nested Value Event Listener to retrieve data from firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

i want to retrieve data from fire base by nested ValueEventListener.
first i find deals present or not in  rooms tree after that is deals present then i want value of discount on that deal.

```
fun deal(room:String): Flowable<List<Deals>>? =
    observeValueEvent(ref.child("rooms/$room/deals"))
            .map { snapshot ->
                snapshot.children.mapNotNull { child ->
                    var deal = child.key
                    if (deal != null) {
                        observeValueEvent(ref1.child("deals/$deal")).map { snapshot1 ->

                            snapshot1.children.mapNotNull { child1 ->

                                var name = child1.getValue().toString()
                                Deals(name)
                            }
                        }

                    }else{
                        null
                    }
                }
            }
```

this is the function for retrieve value from deals.
for  ValueEventListener i  make different function

```
 private fun observeValueEvent(query: Query): Flowable<DataSnapshot> = Flowable
        .create({ emitter ->
            val valueEventListener = object : ValueEventListener {
                override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                    emitter.onNext(snapshot)
                }

                override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                    if (!emitter.isCancelled) {
                        emitter.onError(Throwable(error.details))
                    }
                }
            }
            emitter.setCancellable { query.removeEventListener(valueEventListener) }
            query.addValueEventListener(valueEventListener)
        }, BackpressureStrategy.LATEST)
```

i tried this way but it gives error

```
"mismatch type , required: Flowable<List<Deals>>, Found: Flowable<any>"
```

Comment: Have you tried to change the return type from `Flowable<any>` to `Flowable<List<Deals>>`?

Comment: how to do that i think return type is already Floawable<list><deals>>

Comment: If it says `Found: Flowable<any>`, it means that the is not what it should be. Try to change it accordingly.